# Simultaneous use of A2DP and HFP bluetooth profiles

Tags: windows, bluetooth, headphones, a2dp

Is there any general support for this in any OS?

I'm trying to use my Sennheiser URBANITE XL Wireless headphones to play a game on Windows 10 and talk on Teamspeak simultaneously. I can't figure out how to make the HFP profile connect after connecting A2DP.

**Update:** Apparently there is official support for this according to the Bluetooth SIG http://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/downloaddoc.ashx?doc_id=49216

**The new question is:** Is this implemented in Windows 10, and if so, how do i use it?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell this is not possible with the "default" Windows drivers (Microsoft Bluetooth Enumerator in Device Manager). I've managed to make this work with a Broadcom based device but only after installing their software.

Comment: I have Broadcom based Bluetooth as well. How did you do it?

Comment: Add it as a suggestion in the Windows 10 feedback center. Otherwise try installing whatever non-Microsoft drivers come with your device.

Comment: I will add that the Windows 8.1 Broadcom drivers from Plugable cause BSODs when used with Skype through HeadsetHelper.

Comment: Hi @AdamBaxter , Can you please provide more details? Can you provide a link to the device and the software you're using ?

Comment: @onlyforthis probably not - as it was almost 2 years ago. The drivers were at https://plugable.com/products/usb-bt4le#drivers